# Limited size IList<T> or ICollection<T> that when adding a new item, first item is discarded

Tags: .net, list, limit, icollection, circular-list

I'm looking for some sort of implementation of `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>` that behaves in such a way that it can hold up to a specified amount of items.

If adding a new item would exceed the limit-amount, the first item should be automatically discarded to make room for the newly added ones.

Comment: This can easily and efficiently be done with a LinkedList. 
int itemsToRemove = maxLength - list.Length ;
while (itemsToRemove > 0){
itemsToRemove--;
list.RemoveAt(0);
}

Comment: There's nothing available in the framework itself. Searching for "circular buffer" might yield something useful.

Comment: WHat other properties are required? is random access important? how often is something read compared to how often something is inserted?
Is memory consumption important or not?

Comment: @Rune FS, I basically need it to be a plain `List<T>` that when I call it's `Add` method, checks if limit has been reached, and if so, will discard last item to make room without any confirmations.

Comment: Which solution did you find in the end? Is my answer anywhere near? If so, could you please mark it as your solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without much more information regarding the requirements (memory, number of reads, number of writes, etc) here's a very basic implementation:

```
class CircularList<T> : ICollection<T>
{
    private readonly int capacity;
    private readonly LinkedList<T> list;

    public CircularList(int capacity)
    {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.list = new LinkedList<T>();
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return this.list.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (this.list.Count == this.capacity)
            this.list.RemoveFirst();

        this.list.AddLast(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        this.list.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return this.list.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        this.list.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        return this.list.Remove(item);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Number of items will be around the 10, number of reads/writes will be a lot and performance is important!

Comment: Then I guess the code I've provided will do just fine. The only thing left to tackle is thread safety.

Comment: Which doesn't matter in my case - the app to run is to be single instance only.